# Select other roles as custom post authors

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, author, capabilities

I created a custom post type ("Organization"), and I've also created a custom user role ("Representative"). Also, I've ensured that the Representative role has read/edit/create/publish post capabilities.

I then, programmatically, assigned a Representative as the "author" of the Organization.

When I am on the Organizations overview screen (WP Admin > Organizations), I see the proper representative in the "Author" column.

However, when editing the Organization, the "Author" dropdown only shows Admin/Editor/Contributors. It does not allow me to view/select Representatives as the author of an organization.

I've searched and cannot find the answer. Am I doing this wrong, or is there a way to hook into WP and have it recognize other roles?

Edit: Here is the Custom Post Type:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_organization_info() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Organizations.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => __( "Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Add New", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Add new Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Edit Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "new_item" => __( "New Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "view_item" => __( "View Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "view_items" => __( "View Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Search Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "not_found" => __( "No Organizations found", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( "No Organizations found in trash", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "parent" => __( "Parent Organization:", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "featured_image" => __( "Organization Logo", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( "Upload Organization Logo", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( "Remove Organization Logo", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( "Use as logo for this Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "archives" => __( "Organization archives", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( "Insert into Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( "Upload to this Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( "Filter Organizations list", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( "Organizations list navigation", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Organizations list", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "attributes" => __( "Organizations attributes", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "name_admin_bar" => __( "Organization", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "item_published" => __( "Organization published", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "item_published_privately" => __( "Organization published privately.", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "item_reverted_to_draft" => __( "Organization reverted to draft.", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "item_scheduled" => __( "Organization scheduled", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "item_updated" => __( "Organization updated.", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Parent Organization:", "hello-elementor-child" ),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Organizations", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "org", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-networking",
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields", "author" ],
        "taxonomies" => [ "organization_services" ],
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];

    register_post_type( "organization_info", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_organization_info' );
```

*Edit* Furthermore, I ensure that the role "Representative" has a user level of at least 1:

[image: uMember User Role Editor]

After making these changes, however, I still did not see the Representative showing in the "Author" dropdown for this custom post type.

I even manually added `wp_user_level` and set it to `2` inside of `wp_usermeta` in the DB, but still didn't work.

Comment: Add a code you used, please.

Comment: @anton Are you wanting me to add my custom post type code? Ok. For custom roles, I'm using the "Ultimate Member" plugin, so there is no code. -- I don't know where else to begin (hooks to use, or approaches to take), or I would provide code that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've ensured that the Representative role has read/edit/create/publish
> post capabilities

Okay, that's good.

But did you also assign the `level_<number>` capability to the role, where the `<number>` is at least `1`? If not, then at least the users in the role need to be manually assigned the level `1` or a greater level (`2`, `3`, etc.).

And the reason is because the Author dropdown on the post editing screen will only include users having a level of at least `1` and the level is stored in a user metadata named `wp_user_level` in a non-Multisite install.

More specifically, the Author dropdown uses [`wp_dropdown_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_users/) (if your post type uses the old/classic editor) or the [`GET /wp/v2/users` endpoint in the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#list-users) (if your post type uses Gutenberg, i.e. enabled in the REST API) with the `who` argument set to `authors` which then includes only those users having a user level of `1` or above. [(see source on Trac)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L322)

So please ensure that the Representative role has the proper *user level capability* so that *new* users will automatically have the above metadata set to the correct value.

For existing users in that role, you could programmatically update their `wp_user_level` metadata (using [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)), or you could use a raw SQL to update that metadata, or if you have WP-CLI installed on your site, then you could easily update individual users using the [`wp user meta update` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/meta/) like so: `wp user meta update 123 wp_user_level 1` (where `123` is the user ID).

### UPDATE

In reply to your comment:

> The meta field I created before was `wp_user_level` inside of the
> usermeta table. However, this meta key has to include the WP table's
> prefix. So, if your wp table prefix is `wp_12` (meaning, your usermeta
> table is named `wp_12_usermeta`), then the `wp_user_level` meta key
> must also have the prefix. So, once I set `wp_12_user_level` to `1`,
> it worked!

Yes, that is correct and sorry for not clarifying about the prefix.. :)

So the user level meta is named following this format: `<blog prefix>user_level`, where the [blog prefix](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_blog_prefix/) is in the form of `<base prefix><site ID>_` *or just `<base prefix>`* (see the Multisite note in the next paragraph), and the base prefix defaults to the WordPress table prefix (`$wpdb->prefix`), e.g. `wp_12_` in your case (note that the prefix includes the last `_`).

Therefore in a stock WordPress install where the table prefix defaults to `wp_`, the user level meta would be named `wp_user_level`; however, if Multisite was enabled, then the name (meta key) would be `wp_2_user_level` if the ID of the current (sub-)site is `2`. The main site, though, always uses the format `<table/base prefix>user_level`, i.e. without the `<site ID>_` part.

Comment: Very helpful! I went into uMember to edit the Role's level, but it did not work. I'm updating my initial question with some additional information. Thank you for helping me get closer--I think you're on the right track! Looking forward to your update

Comment: "I even manually added `wp_user_level` and set it to `2` inside of `wp_usermeta` in the DB" - how exactly did you do that? Are you 100% sure you updated the correct user(s)? But now that the role has the user level cap, try creating a new user and assign the user to that role, then see if that user appears in the dropdown?

Comment: I found the solution! The meta field I created before was `wp_user_level` inside of the usermeta table. However, this meta key has to include the WP table's prefix. So, if your wp table prefix is `wp_12` (meaning, your usermeta table is named `wp_12_usermeta`), then the `wp_user_level` meta key must also have the prefix. So, once I set `wp_12_user_level` to `1`, it worked! Thank you for helping me find the solution! -- Add the part about the prefix to your answer, and it's golden. I'll accept your answer

Comment: Thanks! I've added that to my answer and I also reworded the fifth paragraph in the original answer. =)